# No adapter attached; skipping layout using recyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a Firebase database that I'm fetching data from, but i just can't  display fetched data (some text and img)

**This is my code in the Fragment:**

```
public class Tab_0 extends Fragment {
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDataBase;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    DatabaseReference mRefA;

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab0,container,false);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mFirebaseDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("--my url here--");
    mRef = mRef.child("pictures");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model,ViewHolder> FirebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model,ViewHolder>(
                    model.class,
                    R.layout.card,
                    ViewHolder.class,
                    mRef
            ){
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,model model,int position){
                    viewHolder.setDetails( getContext() , model.getImage());
                }
            };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

**and i get this from LogCat**

> No adapter attached skipping layout

I had this outside **onCreateView** method as suggested before (in another question here) but nothing

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model,ViewHolder> FirebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model,ViewHolder>(
                    model.class,
                    R.layout.card,
                    ViewHolder.class,
                    mRef
            ){
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,model model,int position){
                    viewHolder.setImage( getContext() , model.getImage());
                }
            };
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

but nothing is showing

**the viewHolder**

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


View mView;

public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;
}

public void setDetails(Context ctx, String image){
    ImageView img = mView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    Picasso.get().load(image).into(img);
}}
```

I set getter and setter method at model class.(variable that necessary for holder class)

Comment: `return inflater.inflate` just ignores everything you have done to your view before.  `inflater.inflate` just creates a new view that you immediately return. Use `return view;`

Comment: did you override onStart and place yourAdapter.startListening() ?

Comment: I did that in the first place, but the issue is still there!

Comment: are you sure that the model is not coming empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok, I got this**

the tab_0 xml file was like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**The solution** is that i didn't give it a context:

```
        tools:context=".Tab_0"
```

Thanks **StackOverFlowrs!**

Comment: `tools:context` does only provide context to the XML preview. how this would attach an adapter?